# Покрасить несколько ячеек таблицы зажав ЛКМ

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

У меня есть html-таблица, кликнув по ячейке, можно изменить цвет ячейки, но их может быть очень много.
Я хочу, чтоб при зажатии ЛКМ и ведя курсором по таблице, все ячейки, на которые наведется курсор, меняли цвет, а при отпускании ЛКМ - переставали менять цвет.
Как это можно реализовать? Желательно, на чистом JS!

Comment: А у меня нет html-таблицы. Штоделать?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

На чистом JS (это базовый пример без поддержки тачскринов, только мышь!):

```js
/* добавление таблицы в разметку (просто пустые ячейки, для демонстрации) */
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<table><tbody></tbody></table>');
const tBody = document.querySelector('tbody');
for (let tr, i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
  if (!(i % 20))
    tr = tBody.insertRow();
  tr.insertCell();
}
/* переменные, и функция сортировки (для использования в обработчике) */
const mathSort = (a, b) => a - b;
let isMbPressed = false,                      // флаг "кнопка мыши зажата"
    range = [[-1, -1], [-1, -1]];             // координаты "углов" выделенного диапазона ячеек, две точки ([столбец, строка])
/* функция обработчика DOM-событий - в ней основная логика */
const handler = evt => {
  const tr = evt.target.closest('tr');
  const getCoords = () => [                   // функция получения табличных координат мыши
    [...tr.cells].indexOf(evt.target),        // индекс ячейки в строке (X-координата)
    [...tr.parentElement.rows].indexOf(tr),   // индекс строки в таблице (Y-координата)
  ];
  switch (evt.type) {                         // ветвление по типу события
    case 'mouseleave':
      if (evt.target === evt.currentTarget)
        isMbPressed = false;                  // при выходе курсора за границы tbody, снимаем флаг зажатия
      break;
    case 'mousedown':
    case 'mouseup':
      isMbPressed = evt.type === 'mousedown';
      range[+!isMbPressed] = getCoords();     // если событие зажатия, запомним как координаты начальной точки (range[0]), иначе как координаты конечной точки (range[1])
    case 'mousemove':
      if (!isMbPressed) break;                // движения мыши без зажатой кнопки не обрабатываем
      range[1] = getCoords();                 // обновляем координату конечной точки диапазона
      console.clear(), console.log(JSON.stringify(range));
      const [col1, col2] = [range[0][0], range[1][0]].sort(mathSort),     // возьмем X-координаты по возрастанию их значений
            [row1, row2] = [range[0][1], range[1][1]].sort(mathSort);     // и Y-координаты аналогично
      [...tBody.rows].forEach((tr, row) => {
        const inRowRange = (row >= row1) && (row <= row2);
        [...tr.cells].forEach((td, col) => {
          const inColRange = (col >= col1) && (col <= col2);
          td.style.background = inRowRange && inColRange ? '#def' : '';   // установка цвета фона ячейки: при вхождении в диапазон и по X и по Y - голубой цвет (выделение), иначе - никакого цвета (нет выделения)
        });
      });
  }
};
['mousedown', 'mouseup', 'mousemove', 'mouseleave'].forEach(   // перебор имен (типов событий), их будет обрабатывать одна общая функция
  evtType => tBody.addEventListener(evtType, handler)          // обработка всех событий на их всплытии (делегируем ее tbody)
);
```

```css
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
td { width: 2rem; height: 2rem; box-sizing: border-box; border: 1px solid #ccc; user-select: none; }
```

Comment: Сейчас вот подумалось что наверное можно сильно оптимизировать выполнение исключением мусорных итераций на `mousemove` (без троттлинга событий) - чисто используя события входа и выхода курсора... Но операции в обработчике останутся те же самые по их сути, алгоритмическая моделька вроде тоже - так что пусть тут остается на мышемуве (это все же только пример, да и банально лень править). Просто если вдруг кто-то читает, попробуйте на `mouseenter` и `mouseleave` то же самое сделать, это по сути "бесплатный" троттлинг средствами DOM :)

Comment: Замечательный, полезный, по крайней мере для меня, ответ. Голосую за. Если возможно, добавьте пожалуйста в код немного поясняющего текста.

Comment: Сначала подумал, что глючит, нестабильный результат почем то. А оказывается это когда выхожу за пределы поля. Может считывать событие на всем документе или условном контейнере, который чуть больше поля для рисования? Отличный ответ!

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, если будут уточняющие вопросы, то конечно добавлю пояснение. А на данный момент, вся реализация кажется настолько очевидной, что даже комменты в коде некуда поставить (хаки и необычные приемы вроде отсутствуют). Да и ТСом запрашивался практический пример ("как можно реализовать?"), а не вводный курс в теорию :) которая, кстати, достаточно обширна в данном случае... всю целиком ее охватить в одном ответе не получится, имхо.

Comment: @Leonid, в примере можно на всем документе отслеживать событие, но такой вариант будет смущать участников (типа "вроде речь шла о таблице, почему тут обработчик не на таблице а на документе?") Выделяются обычно ячейки в `tbody`, и пример исходит из этого. Сброс флага зажатия мыши (при выходе за пределы тейбл бади) пришлось добавить из-за того что отжатие ловить невозможно при выходе за элемент с обработчиком - если добавить на документ, та же проблема будет и при выходе зажатой мыши за окно браузера... то есть, идеального решения в этом плане нет по сути, только один из компромиссов возможен))

Comment: Хотя, я могу быть неправ и снятие флага на документе предпочтительнее. Трудно сказать, какое поведение тут более ожидаемо. С одной стороны, если выделяем в таблице, то незачем курсор из нее выводить - с другой стороны, на краевых ячейках может рука дрогнуть и потеря селекшна при этом может раздражать юзера...

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, вполне хочется, просто дайте хоть намек что именно объяснить :) тут и DOM, и работа с событиями через делегирование, и чуточка арифметики, и несколько js-методов... Не писать же целый учебник начиная с "вот компьютер, а вот его манипулятор типа мышь"))

Comment: Добавил комментарии в код, может это и правда окажется полезным.

Comment: @yar85 Благодарю. Это будет точно полезно!

Comment: а на айпеде не работает

Comment: @nörbörnën, так точно - у мобильных устройств другие события эмитятся при зажатии. Боюсь что комплексный пример с поддержкой тачскрина будет значительно сложнее (насколько помню, в плане стандартизации обработки тапов/холдов там творится разброд и шатание - то есть, нужно будет кучку условий добавлять, которые усложнят код). Но сталкивался давно, и может сейчас уже полегче стало... постараюсь глянуть это попозже.